# what is the fastest way range search

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, oracle

I have a table that store ipFrom,ipTo,Country,isp etc. table name is ipLocation. I want to find client ip's isp and country. ipLocation table have approximately 10 millions rows. So performance is important  Do you think what is the best or optimized solution? I want to solve this problem with stored procedure.

Table sample data

```
ipFrom(bigint)       ipTo(bigint)   Code(varchar)    Country(varchar)     ISP(varchar)
16781312             16785407       "JP"             "JAPAN"              "BEACON NC INC."
16785408             16793599       "CN"             "CHINA"              "CHINANET GUANGDONG PROVINCE NETWORK"
16793600             16809983       "JP"             "JAPAN"              "ENERGIA COMMUNICATIONS INC."
```

**User client ip:** 16784408

I tried sequential search but that is very slow.

Note: ipFrom,ipTo is bigint and client ip is long type

Comment: Try to include your table structure in a formatted way, along with sample of your data. and tell us also what solutions did you try and found to be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a simple Range query like

```
SELECT ipFrom,ipTo,Country,ISP
FROM ipLocation l
WHERE @UserClientIP BETWEEn l.ipFrom AND l.ipTo
```

WHERE `@UserClientIP`can be a Parameter of your procedure. If that is running slow, check the query execution plan. First guess is a missing index. Try this statment:

```
SELECT i.object_id,i.name index_name,i.type_desc,t.name table_name,c.name column_name
FROM sys.indexes i
    JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id=i.object_id
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=ic.object_id AND c.column_id=ic.column_id
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id=i.object_id
WHERE t.name='ipLocation'
```

It should return you something like

```
object_id      index_name            type_desc         table_name      column_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3278483        IX_your_index_name    NONCLUSTERED      ipLocation      ipFrom
9856985        IX_your_index_name_2  NONCLUSTERED      ipLocation      ipTo
```

If you don't find such rows you should create indices on `ipFrom` and `ipTo` columns.

**UPDATE**
I just saw you tagged your question with oracle and sql-server. The statements for index checking are for SQL Server.